# Database applications crashing

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Currently creating an app that copies an sql database from assets and then allows me to query search it by year, movie name and show all results in a text view. Getting a fatal error that just crashes the application instantly and not sure what to do.. Included the lines that give me the error under the code.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.artis.sqldatabase.MainActivity">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/MainTable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ApplicationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Robin Williams Filmography"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/SearchTable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/MainTable">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/YearEdit"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Year"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/MovieEdit"
        android:layout_width="283dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Movie Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/ButtonTable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/SearchTable">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/YearButton"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search By Year" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/MovieButton"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search By Movie" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/AllButton"
        android:layout_width="84dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="All" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/ResultTable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ButtonTable" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ResultView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</TableRow>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.example.artis.sqldatabase;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
private static final String DATABASE_PATH =
        "/data/data/com.example.artis.sqldatabase/databases/";
private static final String DATABASE_PATH2 =
        "/data/data/com.example.artis.sqldatabase/databases";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ActorsFilmography.db";
private static final String LOG_TAG = "FILMOGRAPHY_DB";
Context ctx;

OpenDatabase sqh;
SQLiteDatabase sqdb;

Button YearButton;
Button MovieButton;
Button AllButton;
EditText YearEdit;
EditText MovieEdit;
TextView ResultView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setUpDatabase();
    InitDataBase();
    SetupControls();
}

public void SetupControls()
{
    YearEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.YearEdit);
    MovieEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.MovieEdit);
    ResultView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ResultView);
    YearButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.YearButton);
    MovieButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.MovieButton);
    AllButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.AllButton);

    AllButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            ResultView.setText("");
            ResultView.setText(sqh.DisplayRecords(sqdb));
        }
    });

    YearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            ResultView.setText("");
            ResultView.setText(sqh.DisplayRecordsBasedOnYear(sqdb, ResultView.getText().toString()));
        }
    });

    MovieButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            ResultView.setText("");
            ResultView.setText(sqh.DisplayRecordsBasedOnMovie(sqdb, ResultView.getText().toString()));
        }
    });
}


public void InitDataBase()
{
    sqh = new OpenDatabase(this);
    sqdb = sqh.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void setUpDatabase()
{
    ctx = this.getBaseContext();
    try
    {
        CopyDataBaseFromAsset();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void CopyDataBaseFromAsset() throws IOException
{
    InputStream in = ctx.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
    Log.w( LOG_TAG , "Starting copying...");
    String outputFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    File databaseFolder = new File( DATABASE_PATH2 );

    if ( !databaseFolder.exists() )
    {
        databaseFolder.mkdir();

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ( (length = in.read(buffer)) > 0 )
        {
            out.write(buffer,0,length);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        in.close();
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Completed.");
        }
    }
}
```

**OpenDatabase.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class OpenDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "src/main/ActorsFilmography.db";

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Filmography";

OpenDatabase(Context context)
{
    super( context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION );
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
}

public String DisplayRecords(SQLiteDatabase sqdb)
{
    String str = "";

    Cursor c = sqdb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Filmography", null);
    if (c != null)
    {
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                String id = c.getString(0);
                str = str + id + ",";
                String Year = c.getString(1);
                str = str + Year + ",";
                String FilmTitle = c.getString(4);
                str = str + FilmTitle + "\n";
                Log.w("FILMOGRAPHY", "ID = " + id + " Songtitle = " + Year + " Movie Title = " + FilmTitle);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    c.close();
    return str;
}

public String DisplayRecordsBasedOnYear(SQLiteDatabase sqdb, String searchYear)
{
    String str = "";

    Cursor c = sqdb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Filmography WHERE YEAR = '" + searchYear + "';", null);
    if (c != null)
    {
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                String id = c.getString(0);
                str = str + id + ",";
                String Year = c.getString(1);
                str = str + Year + ",";
                String FilmTitle = c.getString(4);
                str = str + FilmTitle + "\n";
                Log.w("FILMOGRAPHY", "ID = " + id + " Songtitle = " + Year + " Movie Title = " + FilmTitle);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        else
        {
            str = "No records found";
        }
    }
    c.close();
    return str;
}

public String DisplayRecordsBasedOnMovie(SQLiteDatabase sqdb, String searchFilmTitle)
{
    String str = "";

    Cursor c = sqdb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Filmography WHERE MOVIE = '" + searchFilmTitle + "';", null);
    if (c != null)
    {
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                String id = c.getString(0);
                str = str + id + ",";
                String Year = c.getString(1);
                str = str + Year + ",";
                String FilmTitle = c.getString(4);
                str = str + FilmTitle + "\n";
                Log.w("FILMOGRAPHY", "ID = " + id + " Songtitle = " + Year + " Movie Title = " + FilmTitle);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        else
        {
            str = "No records found";
        }
    }
    c.close();
    return str;
    }
}
```

My current errors that im getting are in MainActivity.java 48th and 96th line. which are:

`InitDataBase();` and `sqdb = sqh.getWritableDatabase();`

application just crashes.. logcat:

```
12-01 22:11:33.806 3784-3784/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.artis.sqldatabase, PID: 3784
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.artis.sqldatabase/com.example.artis.sqldatabase.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File src/main/ActorsFilmography.db contains a path separator
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File src/main/ActorsFilmography.db contains a path separator
at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename(ContextImpl.java:2165)
at android.app.ContextImpl.getDatabasePath(ContextImpl.java:695)
at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:644)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:289)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
at com.example.artis.sqldatabase.MainActivity.InitDataBase(MainActivity.java:96)
at com.example.artis.sqldatabase.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: What have you tried? How did you get to this point? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some details about the style of question that tends to get useful answers, here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your DB name.
You declared:

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "src/main/ActorsFilmography.db";
```

This contains a path separator (i.e. '/'). This is not allowed.
If you change it to `ActorsFilmography` it'll probably fix this problem (without the `.db` because it'll already set the extension as `.db` since it's a database).

Comment: that worked, thank you but now it says in logcat
`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Filmography (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Filmography` when i have made a table in the database that is called Filmography

Comment: @Bubuuh I recommend that you read up on the subject itself [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm) or [here](https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/), this is a basic problem that you can fix by googling it or following one of the links I linked here.

Comment: Okay thanks.. still will mark it as solved since the main issue i was having was solved.. thank you